# Exibir/Esconder "Termos De Uso" ao clicar em checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como faço para que, ao marcar um checkbox, ele libere um conteúdo do site?

Por exemplo, quero fazer um sistema de termos de uso, onde ao clicar em "aceito os termos" ele libere o botão para prosseguir com o conteúdo.

Eu fiz da seguinte forma, criei uma coluna no banco de dados com o nome de "termos", "tamanho 11" do tipo "INT" e então, fiz uma consulta utilizando sessões da seguinte forma:

```
 if($_SESSION['termos'] == 1){
    //ele exibe o conteudo direto sem exibir os termos de uso
} else {
    //exibe os termos de uso com a checkbox e ao selecionar a checkbox é liberado o botão para prosseguir. Ao clicar no botão ele altera o campo "termos" do usuario logado para 1 e assim não exibe mais os termos
}
```

Comment: Alfredo, para isso você vai precisar usar um javascript, ou outra linguagem que não seja somente html. Ou então algum estilo css que exiba isso com um :checked. Mas para podermos te ajudar, você precisa fornecer o seu código, ou uma parcela dele, para sabermos o que você tem, o que já tentou e identificar o que pode estar acontencendo.

Comment: eu fiz da seguinte forma, criei uma coluna no banco de dados com o nome de termos tamanho 11 do tipo INT e ai fiz uma consulta utilizando sessões da seguinte forma if($_SESSION['termos'] == 1){
ele exibe o conteudo direto sem exibir os termos de uso
}else {
exibe os termos de uso com a checkbox ai ao selecionar a checkbox ele libera o botão para prosseguir e ao clicar no botão ele altera o campo termos do usuarios logado para 1 e assim não exibe mais os termos
}

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com esses detalhes.

Comment: Alfredo, essa abordagem sua não a melhor. Poste se código e explique melhor, que com certeza você terá uma resposta satisfatória. A meu ver, você precisa apenas criar um campo par checar se foi aceito ou não os termos. Isso é, se aceitar os termos for algo obrigatório.

Comment: Com `PHP` não é o melhor método de fazer isso, pois ele não é "dinâmico". Você está usando algo em JavaScript? Como jQuery, por exemplo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa solução utiliza apenas CSS. Não é o melhor modo de fazer isso, pois você fica limitado a uma estrutura de código. A `div` que contém o texto deve estar logo em seguida do `input checkbox`, caso contrário, não irá funcionar.

O seu CSS ficaria assim:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #termoTexto{
    display: block;
}
#termoTexto {
    display:none;
}
```

E o HTML assim:

```
<label>Mostrar termos:</label> <input type="checkbox" id="termos" />
<div id="termoTexto">
    Seus termos estarão aqui
</div>
```

Veja um exemplo funcional: http://jsfiddle.net/wy0no7f5/1/

A recomendação, para que você tenha mais liberdade e dinâmica em seu sistema seria utilizar um javascript, por exemplo.

---

#### Editado

Fazer um processo desse através do PHP não é o correto, pois para isso você teria que:

- Ter uma tabela no banco para cada pessoa que acessar o sistema, seja ele cadastrado ou visitante (diria que é impossível);
- Alterar o dado dessa tabela, caso o usuário saia da página sem clicar novamente no `checkbox`, esse valor se manterá como `true` (ou como ele tenha deixado antes de sair da página);
- Para verificar se ele clicou, você precisaria fazer uma consulta ao banco de dados, o que pode ser "lento" (comparado à outros métodos);

Em resumo, com PHP (pelo menos eu desconheço) não há um modo de fazer esse sistema que você procura.

---

#### Editado 2:

Fiz um exemplo bem simples utilizando apenas jQuery. Neste exemplo você tem mais liberdade, pois ele não precisa estar em uma ordem. Você pode ter os elementos em qualquer local em sua página.

Mas, para isso você vai precisar inserir o jQuery em seu projeto. Caso não conheça, [dê uma olhada nesse link](http://www.escolacriatividade.com/tutorial-jquery-o-que-e-e-como-usar-o-jquery/), existem outros por aí, só pesquisar.

Exemplo básico do `jQuery` usado:

```
$('.termos').click(function() {
    $('.meuTermo').toggle(1000);
});
```

Essa função cria um *toggle*, ou seja, em cada clique ele exibe (caso esteja oculta) ou oculta (caso esteja visível), tudo automático, não precisas fazer mais nada, com exceção de definir se estará visível ou não no estado inicial. No seu caso ela estará escondida, então usamos o CSS:

```
.meuTermo {
    display:none; /* mantem a div escondida no inicio da página */
}
```

Exemplo funcionando com `jQuery`: http://jsfiddle.net/q71qne54/

Obs.: Lógico, esse é um exemplo básico. Se você deseja algo mais robusto, com mais segurança, este não seria o melhor método, mas com isso você tem a ideia geral e já teria por onde começar.